# How to filter MapType field of a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe, where one of the fields is of MapType....I can fetch data of any of the keys of the maptype field, but am unable to do when I apply a filter for a specific value of a specific key...

```
val line = List (("Sanjay", Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)), ("Taru", Map("one" -> 10, "two" -> 20)) )
```

I created RDD & DF of above List & am trying to fetch in DF, Map Values where value if >= 5 .....But I get below exception in Spark Repl.. Kindly help

```
val rowrddDFFinal = rowrddDF.select(rowrddDF("data.one").alias("data")).filter(rowrddDF("data.one").geq(5))
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) data#1
>   missin
>                                                     //| g from data#3 in operator !Filter (data#1[one] AS one#4 >= 5);
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalys
>                                                     //| is(CheckAnalysis.scala:38)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer
>                                                     //| .scala:42)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAn
>                                                     //| alysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:121)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAn
>                                                     //| alysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:50)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala
>                                                     //| :98)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnaly
>                                                     //| sis(CheckAnalysis.scala:50)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyze
>                                                     //| r.scala:42)
>                                                     //|     at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLCont
>                                                     //| ext.scala:931)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To access values from an `Array` or `Map` column you can use `Column.getItem` method:

```
rowrddDF
 .where($"data".getItem("one").geq(5))
 .select($"data".getItem("one").alias("data"))
```

If you prefer `filter` after `select` you cannot use `rowrddDF.apply` anymore. Instead you should access aliased column directly:

```
df
  .select($"data".getItem("one").alias("data"))
  .filter($"data".geq(5))
```

Comment: I did it as follows....yr recommendation worked well.   

`
val lastrddDFF = rowrddDF.select(rowrddDF("data").getItem("one").alias("data")).where( col("data").geq(5))
`
Thank you